# Gradle scy issue

Tags: android, android-studio

i am taking a course in Coursera and the instructors uploaded a simple project of a Map
when i try to import it or clone it from gitlab it shows me this message.

**- i tried to delete the gradle file and restart the android studio.**

**- i tried invalidate cach / restart.**

can someone please explain the problem and how i can fix it ?
thank you all previously.

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQFLt.png)

here is the project : https://gitlab.com/vandy-aad-2/MapLocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your need to update a few file gradle.

build.gradle(app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "course.maplocation"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle(MapLocation):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Fri Sep 02 18:48:56 CDT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Please give me access to the GitLab. my account @javaddehban

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem the problem in general ?